# Dealing with large numbers in php

Tags: php, integer, max

```
$k = bcmul(PHP_INT_MAX ,PHP_INT_MAX);
echo number_format($k,0,'','');
```

How can I display the exact result of $k?

I know that php converts an integer into a float whenever it exceeds the maximum value but I still don't get the right result from the above multiplication.

Comment: what is `bcmul`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php .........

Comment: @MonkeyZeus   https://eval.in/1055264

Comment: @AlivetoDie I am not sure why that site chose to install PHP without the bcmath library but that's their prerogative http://us3.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php Try it at https://3v4l.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need `number_format($k,0,'','');`??

Just:

```
echo bcmul(PHP_INT_MAX ,PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Comment: You are right. it doesn't make sense to format it since the function handles large numbers, but I am still wondering why number_format func substruct 1 from the final result?

Comment: I don't recall what those parameters do so once I refresh myself then I'll see if I can answer that

Answer (score -1):

Print the value as string (reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php#110658)

```
printf('%s', $k);
```